# What is the semantic difference between everybody and anybody in `doing` context?

Tags: difference, word-in-context, semantics

Please explain what should I choose for what context in the following examples:

`it lets everybody do whatever they want`
`it lets anybody do whatever they want`

What is the semantic difference?

Comment: Everybody is all relevant people; anybody is one relevant person.

Comment: everybody: all the people; anybody=any person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice depends on whether you are targeting the statement at individuals or at the group. So you might say:

> Anybody who needs to use the toilet should go before the show.

Here you are thinking of individual actions and **any** is the better fit.

On the other hand, you might say:

> Everybody who bought a ticket for the show will get a refund.

Here you are thinking of the people as a group, of all those who bought tickets, so **every** is the better fit.

What dictates your choice is the context. In many contexts, either word will fit. This is true of your examples. The choice would depend on the context, what you are referring to and the make-up of the group concerned.